# Windows 7 kms activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, unattended

I have been preparing for a Windows 7 migration in a couple of schools and have prepared loads of images that are set for KMS activation.

I have just realized that on the unattend file for all images I have disabled automatic activation I must have left the setting in from the initial reference image.

Will the KMS server still pick the machines up and activate them or will I need to run a script on them individually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running [VAMT 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11936) (Volume Activation Management Tool) is a breeze to activate as many machines as you want.

Just make sure all of the machines:

- Are powered on
- You have a user account with administrative access to all of them (if you're using an Active Directory domain, just use VAMT from an Enterprise Admin account, preferably on the server)
- Are all connected to the Internet (you could use an activation "proxy" but it's easier like this)

Open VAMT and add the computers (by IP address or by scanning Active Directory), then select all > right-click > Update Status.  This will contact the computers and check which ones are activated, invalid or on grace period, (other weird statuses as well).

Then you can filter out just the ones that need activation.  Just select them all > right-click > Activate > Online Activate.

It's really easy